Is there a shortcut to translate page in Microsoft Edge?
My goal is to translate a page using a keyboard shortcut.
For example, when user visit a website, it can press a keyboard shortcut to translate the page.
This is a use case because the translate feature do not translate text inside a Menu.

Translate inside what sort of menu? Do you mean menus inside a web page, or a context menu? Is your question about Edge, or Chrome? You mention Edge specifically in the title, but you have added the Chrome and Chromium tags, making the context of your question less clear.

There does not appear to be a default keyboard shortcut for translation. However, each of these browsers will prompt to translate any pages that are not in the user's default language with a popup at the top of the page. Whether every part of the page can be translated will vary. If, for instance, images contain text, that will not be translated, though any alt-text may be translated.

@music2myear Hi, I tagged Chromium because I assume that Microsoft Edge use Chromium.

@music2myear sometimes it failed to translate the menu that is not hidden with CSS display: none but instead added to the DOM when the user hover over the menu. For example, https://nwpu.edu.cn, if you translate the page, and then hover over the menu, the submenu will not be translated.

Then your question is wrong. You do not want to know whether there is a keyboard shortcut, you want to know how to translate elements that were/are hidden when the translate process runs and so when they show later they're not translated. Please ask the question that you're actually having so that we have a better chance of actually helping you solve the problem that you are experiencing.
